# Multi version of julia deployed, but only first environment was created correctly

Tags: julia, environment

I tried to install julia 1.4.2 and 1.6.2 on my machine. Each can be started with the link, but firstly installed version which is 1.6.2 has correct environments generated, while secondly added version 1.4.2 has empty environment in my .julia/environment/ path. And, now I have no way to add packages for version 1.4.2 cause no Pkg is detected from 1.4.2. Did anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you getting an error when you try to add packages for 1.4.2? The environment file should be created automatically when you install a package.

Comment: see my answer to your other post - this is what you need to do :)

Comment: Yes, no environment file created. I suspect the reason is that I build the julia from the source and something went wrong.